# Get AttributeError when writing a foreign key relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After reading the DRF tutorial, I try to write a API but get 'Request' object has no attribute 'customer' when I send post request to `/api/images/`.I just try to copy and modify codes from the DRF tutorial. Can someone tells me what's going wrong?
(I'm sure that my foreign key relationship break the api because when i comment codes about foreign key it works.)

(Customer is the foreign key of the image.)

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Image(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    figure = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False)
```

serializers.py

```
# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customers = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='customer-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'username', 'customers', 'email']

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='image-detail', read_only=True)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'images', 'owner']

class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='customer.email')
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'figure', 'customer']
```

views.py

```
class UserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated,
  ]
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user



class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """
        The create() method of our serializer will now be passed an additional 'owner' field,
        along with the validated data from the request.
        """
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser, )
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
    #                       IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(customer=self.request.customer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`self.request.user`** to get the authenticated user in Django instead of `self.request.customer`. Because, DRF requests doesn't have any attribute named `customer` but, **`user`**. So, it should be as,

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(customer=self.request.user)
```